# How to fix the legend of plotly 3D scatter plots in Python?

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, legend, scatter-plot

I am trying to create some 3D scatter plots using plotly in Python. I have a data frame with some personality traits and cluster labels, and I want to plot the TSNE embeddings for each trait using color and symbol to represent the trait and cluster values. Here is my code:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Replace y and n with numbers

df2 = df.replace({'y': 1, 'n': 0})

# Assign cluster labels

df2 = df2.assign(Cluster=labels)

# Create a list of plot titles for each personality trait
plot_titles = ['Extraversion', 'Neuroticism', 'Agreeableness', 'Conscientiousness', 'Openness']

# Plot the TSNE embeddings for each personality trait
for i, trait in enumerate(['cEXT', 'cNEU', 'cAGR', 'cCON', 'cOPN']):
  # Create a single plot figure for each trait
  fig = px.scatter_3d(df2,
                      x=embeddings_3d[:, 0], y=embeddings_3d[:, 1], z=embeddings_3d[:, 2],
                      color = df2[trait], symbol=df2['Cluster'],
                      color_discrete_map={0: '#FF0000', 1: '#0000FF'},
                      size_max=1, symbol_map={0: 'circle', 1: 'square', 2: 'diamond', 3: 'cross', 4: 'x'},
                      opacity=0.3)
  # Update the layout of the plot figure with the title
  fig.update_layout(title=plot_titles[i])
  
  # Show the plot figure
  fig.show()
```

However, the legend of the plots is a mess. It is showing a gradient legend for color and cluster representation, but I don't need gradients. My categories are labels and therefore categorical. Just names! Also, it's all mixed. So what I need to present are just the labels of the cluster each datapoint represent.

[image: Just an example]

How can I fix the legend of my plots to show only the cluster labels with the corresponding color and symbol? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit 1: Here is the data:[df2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ox5dTlcSUOx4rup1DOTMd5Uc-d3JLYJS/view?usp=sharing)

Edit 2: Here are the embeddings: [embeddings_3d](https://%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qnnxwdkyas1TUCXucRy2WzZ4dyI4GSAW/view?usp=sharing)

Edit 3: Here I paste an example of what I'm talking about. The idea is to generate a similar plot but with colors identifying the presence or absence of a personality trait and symbols identifying belonging to a cluster.

[image: Embeddings colored by clusters]

Comment: Could you provide us with the dataset? You are using a variable df which is not defined

Answer (score 0):

This is a draft of a possible solution, since I am still missing few parameters not provided in the question (labels and embeddings_3d). Check whether this is what you were looking for or not. Notice, however, that I was not able to run the code so this is something I have just written on top of my head.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')
embeddings_3d = pd.read_csv('embeddings_3d.csv')

# Replace y and n with numbers
df2 = df.replace({'y': 1, 'n': 0})

# Create a list of plot titles for each personality trait
plot_titles = ['Extraversion', 'Neuroticism', 'Agreeableness', 'Conscientiousness', 'Openness']

# Initialize an empty list to store figure objects
figures = []

# Plot the TSNE embeddings for each personality trait
for i, trait in enumerate(['cEXT', 'cNEU', 'cAGR', 'cCON', 'cOPN']):
    # Create a 3D scatter plot for the current trait
    trace = go.Scatter3d(
        x=embeddings_3d.iloc[:, -3],  # Third-last column
        y=embeddings_3d.iloc[:, -2],  # Column before the last
        z=embeddings_3d.iloc[:, -1],  # Last column
        marker=dict(
            size=4,
            color=df2[trait],
            colorscale='Viridis',
            opacity=0.5,
        ),
        name=trait,
    )

    # Create a figure for the current trait
    fig = go.Figure(data=[trace])

    # Update the figure layout
    fig.update_layout(
        scene=dict(
            xaxis_title='X',
            yaxis_title='Y',
            zaxis_title='Z',
        ),
        title=plot_titles[i],
    )

    # Append the figure to the list
    figures.append(fig)

# Display the figures
for fig in figures:
    fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

The labels are the last column of the df2. I shared with you the updated version of the data so just ignore this line: df2 = df2.assign(Cluster=labels).

Here is the data for the variable embeddings_3d: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qnnxwdkyas1TUCXucRy2WzZ4dyI4GSAW/view?usp=sharing

I tried it on my code but couldn't get it done.

Comment: Try to check the updated code and tell me if that was your original goal. I have not edited much, just added the labels.

Comment: Not exactly. I see your code ignores completely the clusters.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been updated and the final example of what was accomplished has been provided, so the answer has been updated.
The change is to create a single graph with a set of colors for each personality trait unit instead of a subplot. This will address active and inactive in the legend.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

# Create trait color set
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
color_list = [[x,y] for x,y in zip(colors[::2], colors[1::2])]
trait_colors = [{0: x[0], 1: x[1]} for x in color_list]

fig = go.Figure()

symbolmap = {0: 'circle', 1: 'square', 2: 'diamond', 3: 'cross', 4: 'x'}

for i, trait in enumerate(['cEXT', 'cNEU', 'cAGR', 'cCON', 'cOPN']):
    colormap = trait_colors[i]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
      x=embeddings_3d.to_numpy()[:, 0][:500],
      y=embeddings_3d.to_numpy()[:, 1][:500],
      z=embeddings_3d.to_numpy()[:, 2][:500],
      mode='markers',
      name=trait,
      marker=dict(
          color=[colormap[x] for x in df2[trait]],
          symbol=[symbolmap[x] for x in df2['Cluster']],
          size=3,
          opacity=0.8))
               )
  
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=750)
fig.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solution is almost there. The problem is that the legend has now labels for each plot of the five traits. That's not what I'm trying to accomplish. Instead, I need to have these labels for clusters.

The idea is to have one plot for each personality trait with its own legend that should allow me to activate or deactivate the visualization of the clusters. The code achieves almost everything but the legends showing clusters.