# Use unique symbols and colors for scatter plot clusters

Tags: plotly, visualization, plotly-python

I want to label each cluster with different colors and symbols.
My scatter plot's legend has double/duplicate labels for each cluster. I only want one label.

```
# Assuming 'X_umap' contains the UMAP coordinates
umap_coords = adata.obsm['X_umap']

# Define marker size based on the 'n_genes_by_counts' column
marker_size = adata.obs['n_genes_by_counts']

# Get unique cluster labels and sort them in chronological order
unique_cluster_labels = sorted(adata.obs['clustering'].unique())

# Create the Plotly scatter plot for UMAP visualization
fig = px.scatter(
    adata.obs,
    x=umap_coords[:, 0],  # Replace with the actual UMAP coordinates column names
    y=umap_coords[:, 1],
    color='clustering',  # Color based on the "clustering" column
    opacity=0.5,
    title=f"Single-cell clusters for Sample {best_sample_id}",
    labels={'X_umap_0': 'UMAP 1', 'X_umap_1': 'UMAP 2'},
    color_discrete_sequence=palette,  # Set the color palette

    # Use a categorical variable for different marker symbols
    symbol=adata.obs['clustering'].astype(str),

    # Set marker size based on 'n_genes_by_counts' column
    size=marker_size,

    size_max=3,  # Adjust the maximum marker size as needed
)

# Rearrange the legend in chronological order
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(sizemode='diameter'))

# Define custom markers for each cluster
custom_markers = {
    cluster_label: {"symbol": custom_symbol}
    for cluster_label, custom_symbol in zip(adata.obs['clustering'].unique(), markers)
}

# Loop through each cluster and update the marker symbol
for cluster_label, custom_marker in custom_markers.items():
    fig.update_traces(marker=custom_marker, selector=dict(name=f'Cluster {cluster_label}'))

# Remove background color and grid
fig.update_layout(
    width=1000,
    height=1000,
    showlegend=True,
    legend_title='Cluster',
    legend=dict(title='Cluster', traceorder='normal'),
    xaxis=dict(showgrid=False),
    yaxis=dict(showgrid=False),
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',  # Remove background color
)
```

Input:
`adata.obs`

```
pd.DataFrame({'n_genes_by_counts': {'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AACTGGTAGTAACCCT': 726,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AAGTCTGAGTCGTTTG': 726,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTAGGTGCAAC': 726,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTTCGACGGAA': 726,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATGAGGGAGGATCGCA': 726},
 'total_counts': {'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AACTGGTAGTAACCCT': 19.34949600387155,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AAGTCTGAGTCGTTTG': 207.8753459530933,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTAGGTGCAAC': 26.130647180889692,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTTCGACGGAA': 33.13786223869093,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATGAGGGAGGATCGCA': -20.95336035054362},
 'sample_id': {'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AACTGGTAGTAACCCT': 'GSE181061',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AAGTCTGAGTCGTTTG': 'GSE181061',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTAGGTGCAAC': 'GSE181061',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTTCGACGGAA': 'GSE181061',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATGAGGGAGGATCGCA': 'GSE181061'},
 'percent_mito': {'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AACTGGTAGTAACCCT': 0.0,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AAGTCTGAGTCGTTTG': 0.0,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTAGGTGCAAC': 0.0,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTTCGACGGAA': 0.0,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATGAGGGAGGATCGCA': 0.0},
 'n_genes': {'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AACTGGTAGTAACCCT': 201,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AAGTCTGAGTCGTTTG': 332,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTAGGTGCAAC': 213,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTTCGACGGAA': 228,
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATGAGGGAGGATCGCA': 219},
 'marker': {'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AACTGGTAGTAACCCT': 'diamond-cross',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AAGTCTGAGTCGTTTG': 'triangle-se-dot',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTAGGTGCAAC': 'star-triangle-down-dot',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTTCGACGGAA': 'bowtie',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATGAGGGAGGATCGCA': 'star-diamond-dot'},
 'louvain': {'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AACTGGTAGTAACCCT': '5',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AAGTCTGAGTCGTTTG': '0',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTAGGTGCAAC': '4',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTTCGACGGAA': '0',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATGAGGGAGGATCGCA': '5'},
 'leiden': {'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AACTGGTAGTAACCCT': '3',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AAGTCTGAGTCGTTTG': '5',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTAGGTGCAAC': '7',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTTCGACGGAA': '5',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATGAGGGAGGATCGCA': '3'},
 'clustering': {'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AACTGGTAGTAACCCT': '3',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_AAGTCTGAGTCGTTTG': '5',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTAGGTGCAAC': '7',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATCATCTTCGACGGAA': '5',
  'Pt17_1249069_1_NA_tumor_CD45+_ATGAGGGAGGATCGCA': '3'}})
```

`adata.obsm`

```
AxisArrays with keys: X_pca, X_umap, X_tsne
```

Current output:
[image]

Desired output:
Legend - 0, 1, 2, 3 etc

[image]

Comment: Are marker colors paired with symbols? Can you present data for the graph?

Comment: Yes, marker colors are paired with symbols. I've added the data.

Comment: You have gone to the trouble of submitting data, but we were unable to produce your graph. Would [my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77036529/how-to-fix-the-legend-of-plotly-3d-scatter-plots-in-python/77041604#77041604) help you with the answers you are expecting?